# How to discover why geomesa-accumulo gets stuck? Where are geomesa-accumulo logs?

Tags: log, geomesa

After saving some data records using Spark Streaming, I usually check those records using the cli with the export command. The point is that sometimes it gets stuck: I would like to know why, but I don't know how. If then I check my simplefeatures with the following command, it gets stuck as well:

```
geomesa-accumulo get-type-names -u myUsername -p myPassword -c myCatalog
```

Are there any logs to check why geomesa-accumulo gets stuck? I can see that hdfs is ok since each node is up and runnning ("in service") from the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

The Accumulo documentation has a section on [troubleshooting](https://accumulo.apache.org/1.9/accumulo_user_manual.html#_troubleshooting). GeoMesa CLI logs will go under $GEOMESA_ACCUMULO_HOME/logs.